# FORTRAN preprocessor truncates statement

Tags: gfortran

When I converted a FORTRAN code using FORTRAN preprocessor, then used gfortran 7.3.0 to compile it, I got the following error

```
module_wrf_error.f90:131:26:`str_with_rc = TRIM(str`
Error: Syntax error in argument list at (1)
0.01user 0.26system 0:00.30elapsed 91%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 7928maxresident)k
0inputs+16outputs (0major+14187minor)pagefaults 0swaps make[2]: [module_wrf_error.o] Error 1 (ignored)
```

I searched the `module_wrf_error.F` in the frame directory and found the statement

```
`str_with_rc = TRIM(str // rc_str)`
```

However, after FORTRAN preprocessor processing, this statement became

```
`str_with_rc = TRIM(str`
```

It was truncated. Do you have any ideas on this error? Thank you.

Comment: Which preprocessor are you using, and with what options? It's likely it's limiting its output to 132 columns (which would be appropriate for conformance with the Fortran standard) but there's no way to answer how to change that without knowing which tool you are using.

Comment: I am using cpp whose version is /usr/ebuild/software/GCCcore/7.3.0/bin/cpp. The option is " -P". I do not know where I should specify the number of columns. Would you please give me more clue? thank you